# How does a MIPS-32 linker convert lw and sw addresses?

Tags: assembly, linker, hex, mips, mips32

I am reading Chapter 2.12 of [Computer Organization and Design](http://ac.aua.am/arm/public/2017-Spring-Computer-Organization/Textbooks/ComputerOrganizationAndDesign5thEdition2014.pdf), trying to understand the logic of a MIPS-32 linker. I understand the concept of linking two object files and absolute reference linking. What I don't understand is the quoted paragraph below explaining the logic for calculating absolute addresses.

> The load and store addresses are harder because they are relative to a base
>   register. This example uses the global pointer as the base register. Figure 2.13
>   shows that $gp is initialized to 1000 8000<sub>hex</sub>. To get the address 1000 0000<sub>hex</sub> (the address of word X), we place 8000<sub>hex</sub> in the address field of lw at address 40 0000<sub>hex</sub>. Similarly, we place 8020<sub>hex</sub> in the address field of sw at address 40 0100<sub>hex</sub> to get the address 1000 0020<sub>hex</sub> (the address of word Y).
>   Page 128

According to the MIPS-32 instruction set for instructions `lw` and `sw`, the immediate offset operand is added to the register operand.

But
1000 8000<sub>hex</sub> + 8000<sub>hex</sub> = 1001 0000<sub>hex</sub> != 1000 0000<sub>hex</sub>
1000 8000<sub>hex</sub> + 8020<sub>hex</sub> = 1001 0020<sub>hex</sub> != 1000 0020<sub>hex</sub>

So maybe I am misunderstanding something and the offsets are being subtracted? Even if that was the case:

1000 8000<sub>hex</sub> - 8000<sub>hex</sub> = 1000 0000<sub>hex</sub> == 1000 0000<sub>hex</sub>
1000 8000<sub>hex</sub> - 8020<sub>hex</sub> = FFFF FE0<sub>hex</sub> != 1000 0020<sub>hex</sub>

**What is happening here?**

Figure 2.13:

[image: MIPS-32 Memory Allocation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16-bit offsets found in the instruction words are *sign-extended* to 32 bits before being added to the base address.

So if the offset found in the instruction word is 0x8000, you get 0x10008000 + 0xFFFF8000 == 0x10000000 (when the result is truncated to 32 bits). And similarly for the second example.

Comment: So it takes advantage of an overflow? Is that a common way of subtracting two numbers?

Comment: You can view 0xFFFF8000 as -32768 if you want to. They're just different ways of describing the same bit pattern.

Comment: As for whether it's common; that depends on whether there's a dedicated subtraction operation available. In this case (for MIPS address calculations) there isn't, so you achieve the same thing by adding a negative value instead.

Comment: Okay, I understand the math now. So why is the `$gp` register not just set to 0x1000 0000? Would you not be able to access the same range of addresses without having to sign-extend?

Comment: My guess would be that the data section of this imaginary system starts at 0x10000000. So by setting `$gp = 0x10008000` you can easily address anything within the first 64kB of the data section.

Comment: What do you mean by "easily address"? Why set `$gp` to the middle of the 64kB region and access +-32kB instead of setting it to the beginning of the region and indexing forward into the 64kB as well as not having to sign-extend? Wouldn't that be "easier"?

Comment: But offsets _are_ sign-extended. So if you wanted to be able to do `$gp`-relative addressing of 0x10000000..0x1000FFFF, that's how you would do it.